# How to use make to build multiple man pages?

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching, gnu-make, manpage

I am trying to automate building `man` pages in my project with make.

I have the following directory structure:

```
  my_project
    man/
      man1/
      man3/
      man5/
      man7/
```

Inside each of those directories, there is one or more `.md` files.

I would like to generate `*.1`, `*.3`, ..., pages when the corresponding `man/man{1,3,5,7}/*.md` is updated.

The relevant parts of my `Makefile` are:

```
MY_DOC := $(wildcard $(MY_PROJECT)/man/*/*.md)

all: $(MY_DOC:%.md=%.1)

%.1 %.3 %.5 %.7 : %.md
  @ronn --roff $?
```

The above is building `.1` pages as intended, but `.3`, `.5` and `.7` *always*.

I can see `$(MY_DOC:%.md=%.1)` is replacing all `.md` with `.1` which is one of the problems, but I don't know how to change that to mean 1, 3, 5 or 7 depending on the parent directory.

Comment: I don't think the `**` means anything other than `*` in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build man pages as intended and still use the [substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html#Substitution-Refs) syntax.

```
MY_DOC := $(MY_PROJECT)/man
MAN1 := $(wildcard $(MY_DOC)/man1/*.md)
MAN3 := $(wildcard $(MY_DOC)/man3/*.md)
MAN5 := $(wildcard $(MY_DOC)/man5/*.md)
MAN7 := $(wildcard $(MY_DOC)/man7/*.md)

all: $(MAN1:%.md=%.1) $(MAN3:%.md=%.3) $(MAN5:%.md=%.5) $(MAN7:%.md=%.7)

%.1 %.3 %.5 %.7 : %.md
  @ronn --roff $?
```

I think there must be a simpler way to achieve this, but this is the best I was able to come up with.

Comment: Try `MAN := $(wildcard $(MY_DOC)/man[1357]/*.md)` and maybe `$(patsubst $(MY_DOC)/man%/,,$(MAN))` if you need to reduce to the basename.

Comment: @tripleee I'd like to simplify the above so I tried `$(wildcard $(MAN)/man[157]/*.md)` which shortens MAN1 to MAN3 above considerably, but I am stuck at coming up with expansions inside `all` using your example.

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure the directory name is always part of the filename you're using, which seems to be the case here, then it is just a matter of using GNU Make's [patsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) function; the syntax you're using now is just a convenient shorthand for simple cases, and your case is more complex.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve the problem using the shorthand syntax, but I would like to see if using `patsubst` can make it any simpler or less repetitive.